# Let $F$ be a field of 8 elements and $A$= {$x\in F$| $x^7$=1 and $x^k$$\neq$1 for all natural number k<1}. Then the number of elements in A is

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $F$ be a field of $8$ elements and $A$= {$x\in F$| $x^7$=1 and $x^k$$\neq$1 for all natural number $k<1$}. Then the number of elements in $A$ is:

a) 1

b) 2

c) 3

d) 6

Please give me some hints. I am very new in Algebra.

Comment: What do you remember about groups of order seven? That is the key here. First review basic properties of groups, and only then try apply them to fields.

Comment: And welcome to Math.SE! If you lurked for any period of time you have undoubtedly noticed that we try to help you solve a homework problem like this yourself. To that end it is helpful, if you include your own thoughts, and give other context (from which course this is, what has been covered up to this point etc).

Comment: yes $\mathbb{Z}_7$

Comment: Ok, so how many elements of $\Bbb{Z}_7$ satisfy the condition of the question. Careful: the group operation in $\Bbb{Z}_7$ is addition, but in the muliplicative group of a field it is, of course, multiplication. Therefore instead of powers you look at _____, and instead of $=1$ you want $=$____? You fill in the blanks :-)

Comment: i got the answer is 6 but very lengthy process. first i did construct a field of 8 elements ($\Bbb{Z}_2$/<$x^3+x^2+1$>) then i checked all condition for all the elements. Is there any other short process?

Comment: Correct. Well done! The shorter process is that because $7$ is a prime, by Lagrange's theorem the order of an element of a group of order seven is either $1$ or $7$. And there can be only one element of order $1$ namely the identity.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: the nonzero elements of a field form a group under multiplication.  Do you know something about groups with $7$ elements?

Comment: yes $\mathbb{Z}_7$